# how to change the root user when executing "user_data" in an AWS instance or how to execute "yarn start" with the ubuntu user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform-provider-aws

I have a problem with Terraform and an AWS EC2 instance. When doing an auto scaling group I require installation through yarn(node js). The problem is because I need to execute the commands with the Ubuntu user and AWS "user_data" by default runs the commands with the root user.

This is my bash code:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
su ubuntu
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm
bash_completion
[[ -s $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh ]] && . $HOME/.nvm/nvm.sh
nvm bash_completion
cd /srv/node/MyProject &&
yarn start:api:qa
```

Answer (score 2):

Run your commands in your user_data, like this:

```
su - ubuntu -c "export NVM_DIR=\"$HOME/.nvm\""
su - ubuntu -c "[ -s \"$NVM_DIR/bash_completion\" ] && . \"$NVM_DIR/bash_completion\" # This loads nvm"
...
```

and so on.
I use the above method on AMZN Default Linux EC2 Instances and that works. So you may have to verify if that works the same on Ubuntu. But basically there are multiple ways of running a command as another user in bash.